# mysql version error in store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

below is my query:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `UpdateDB_Base_Url`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateDB_Base_Url()
BEGIN

DECLARE @rownum INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE @tbname VARCHAR(50);


WHILE @rownum<105  DO 

SET @tbname= SELECT CONCAT((SELECT dbname FROM temp_db WHERE rownum=@rownum),'.','core_config_data');

UPDATE  @tbname t
SET    t.`value` =CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`value`, 1,LOCATE('.' ,`value`)),'magapa.ns-staging.com.au')
WHERE  t.`value` LIKE '%staging-php%';

SET @rownum=@rownum+1;
END WHILE;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

temp_db table has db names with row number upto 104 records. here i am trying to update a table by going through all dbs in my server and i am getting following error

```
Query: CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateDB_Base_Url() begin declare @rownum int default 1; declare @tbname varchar(50); while @rownum<105 do SET ...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@rownum int default 1;
declare @tbname varchar(50);
while @rownum<105  do 
SET @' at line 3
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code.

1. You need not qualify local variables with `'@'` symbol. They are for
   user/session variables.
2. You can read output of an expression into a local variable using
   `select ... into`. No explicit `set` and `select` are required.
3. You can't just `update` a table with table name read from a
   variable, directly. You have to use Prepared Statement.

**Change your code as below**:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `UpdateDB_Base_Url` $$

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateDB_Base_Url()
BEGIN
  DECLARE _rownum INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE _tbname VARCHAR(50);

  SET _rownum := 1;

  WHILE _rownum < 105  DO 
    SELECT CONCAT( dbname, ',', 'core_config_data' ) 
      INTO _tbname 
      FROM temp_db 
     WHERE rownum = _rownum;

    SET @sql := CONCAT( 'UPDATE ', _tbname, ' t ' );
    SET @sql := CONCAT( @sql, ' SET t.`value` = ' );
    SET @sql := CONCAT( @sql, ' CONCAT( SUBSTRING( t.`value`, 1, ' );
    SET @sql := CONCAT( @sql, ' LOCATE( \'.\', t.`value` ) )' );
    SET @sql := CONCAT( @sql, ', \'magapa.ns-staging.com.au\' )';
    SET @sql := CONCAT( @sql, ' WHERE  t.`value` LIKE \'%staging-php%\'' );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;

    SET _rownum := _rownum + 1;
  END WHILE;

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```